# jQuery block a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I want to use inline loading (via AJAX) on my website, while at the same time preserving (some) functionality for people without access to Javascript (if they still exist).

My menu's:

```
<?php
echo "<h3 id='title'></h3>";
if (empty($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    echo "<a href='index'>Home</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='register'>Register</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='login'>Log In</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='browser'>Browse MarketPlace</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='support'>Support us!</a>";
}
elseif (!empty($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    echo "<a href='index'>Home</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='overview'>Account Overview</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='browser'>Browse MarketPlace</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='sell'>Sell Items</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='logout'>Logout</a> <br> ";
    echo "<a href='support'>Support us!</a>";
}
?>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
        var dataUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        if (dataUrl != "") {
            loadPage(dataUrl);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I am especially worried about the need to block the original `a href` call, the native browser one.

It has worked entirely fine when I used something custom like `<a data-url='index'>`. Then I tried the new version and it did not work as expected without `return false;`, but now it does, so I'm not too sure about that.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use **[event.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
            var dataUrl = $(this).attr("href");
            if (dataUrl != "") {
                loadPage(dataUrl);
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: You don't need `return false` on the last line.

Comment: @dcodesmith agreed i just mention the event.preventDefault() no worry i will update it

Comment: Should I worry about event propegation aswell?

Comment: if use use click event on anchor tag then stop it default behavior and no need to worry dude so cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`event.preventDefault()`

This cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

Refer **[event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)**